# Get a number from a string from end to dash

Tags: javascript, regex

I have URL and i need to get the id, which is at the end of the string. The URL is looking this */questions/M%C3%A4rkte+que+sentra-361433*. I need to get the last number to the dash.
I am trying to use this expression but it grabs all numbers.

```
let str = 'questions/M%C3%A4rkte+que+sentra-361433';
let id = str.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'');
```

In this concrete example, I got 34361433, but it should be 361433

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Regex:

```
let str = 'questions/M%C3%A4rkte+que+sentra-361433';
let id = str.match(/(?:-)(\d+)$/)[1];
console.log(id);
```

As another way without Regex, if it is applicable to you:

```
let str = 'questions/M%C3%A4rkte+que+sentra-361433';
let splitted = str.split('-');
let id = splitted[splitted.length - 1];
console.log(id);
```

Comment: The first option worked! Thanks a lot!